# What are the differences between apache-commons serialization and JDK serialization?

Tags: java, apache-commons

JDK's object serialization mechanism has some flaws(poor performance, huge bytes ). Is Apache's `SerializationUtils` better than JDK's ?

Comment: `JDK's object serialization mechanism has some flaws(poor performance, huge bytes )` Would be good to site evidence of this claim

Comment: I work on an application that has 500K lines of code that uses the JDK's object serialization extensively.  Our product has been used by major vendors for many years and they often report that it performs extremely well.

Comment: Yeah, the only concern I've ever heard about Java's serialization is security, and that's when people deserialize untrusted data, which they shouldn't.

Comment: @ZackMacomber   Thanks for your comment. I've never done performance test but maybe serialize object into JSON is a better choice ?

Comment: @Neo Not sure on that...for what it's worth, I typically use `Jackson` for serializing an object into JSON and I've found it performs well

Comment: As an educated guess, you'd use less bandwidth but spend more cpu time deserializing. Less bandwidth because the class metadata are not transmitted, more cpu because using a library is bound to be more intensive than doing a standard java instance initialization. I might be missing a few things thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [their API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html#serialize(java.io.Serializable)), I'm quite confident this class is provided only to make the (de)serialization easier to code and that the underlying (de)serialization is made by the JDK's methods.

Their [publicly available sources](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) confirm this.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need to know